# Are saving throws stacked up when multi-classing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, saving-throw

We are playing regular D&D 3.5 campaign and I was wondering if the saving throws are added to each other when multi-classing.

For example: A barbarian gets +2 FORT, +0 REF and +0 WILL, at level one. If I take fighter at level 2, also +2 FORT, +0 REF and +0 WILL, would that mean that my character now has +4 FORT?

Comment: Possible dupe
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/multiclass-total-saving-throw-adjustment-in-pathfinder

Comment: @Wyrmwood That's for Pathfinder. D&D 3.5e is similar but different.

Comment: "...saves work the same way in both so..." from KRyan's answer

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Each level selected provides cumulative benefits.

This also applies to skill points and base attack bonus. See the section on multi-classing in the PHB or [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/multiclass.htm) (under classes) for details. As you are selecting base classes, there are usually no prerequisites (see monk and paladin for exceptions).

Please note that when leveling up and selecting prestige classes, those may have prerequisites which are required to be met before taking that level. There are other small details, but it does not seem relevant to your question, so I will avoid expounding.

Comment: Great answer, but to make it complete, consider adding the "fractional saving throws" alternative rule found in Unearthed Arcana. When using this rule, characters add a fraction to each saving throw when they level up (1/2 for a good saving throw, +2 every first class level, and +1/3 every poor saving throw).

Comment: That was one of the things I intended to be covered by the "other small details" I wasn't going into. ^^ Had the OP mentioned UA or OA or similar, I would have brought that up. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Also worth noting, the entries for higher levels of a class show the total, not the amount you gain. To find the amount you gain, compare with the level below. Doesn't affect a multiclass lvl 1/1 character, but important to know when you go to lvl 2/1.

Comment: Absolutely correct! That is a spot of potential confusion that didn't occur to me to point out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, until you reach 20th character level (20 class-levels) you keep stacking the bonuses for all class-levels you have. The same applies to all other class-related benefits, like base attack for example.

After (a total of) 20th character level, Epic rules for advancement come into play, as found in the DMG.